# Exim intercept shadow_transport executing but no data appended to file

Tags: exim

I would like to keep a copy of every email that transits through my exim SMTP in a PostgreSQL database. I need the basic info:

`From, To, CC, BCC and email body`

as I might need it to be checked by the company managers if there are fishy activities going on. (Privacy is not an issue where I live!)

I have setup a `shadow_transport` for this to be accomplished:

**Exim Configuration:**

```
maildir_home:
  debug_print = "T: maildir_home for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_MAILDIR_LOCATION
  directory = MAILDIR_HOME_MAILDIR_LOCATION
  .else
  directory = $home/Maildir
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_DIRECTORY
  create_directory
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_FILE
  create_file = MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_FILE
  .endif
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  maildir_format
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_DIRECTORY_MODE
  directory_mode = MAILDIR_HOME_DIRECTORY_MODE
  .else
  directory_mode = 0700 
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_MODE
  mode = MAILDIR_HOME_MODE
  .else
  mode = 0600 
  .endif
  mode_fail_narrower = false
  shadow_transport = save_to_db

save_to_db:
  debug_print = "PG: $sender_address"
  driver = pipe 
  command = /usr/sbin/exim_save_to_db "test" "test2"
  user = Debian-exim
  group = mail
```

This is just a simple script that appends test and test2 to `/tmp/eximtest` file which I will expand when I get it working.

**The script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Get data from exim server and save to postgres database for future reference
# Args: 1->recipients (from to bcc etc ) 2->emailbody
echo "$1" >> /tmp/eximtest
echo "$2" >> /tmp/eximtest

# return 0 as success for Exim
echo 0
```

Running `exim_save_to_db` from command line with any 2 arguments will do the job. From exim it will not even though in the logs I do find the shadow transport has been executed:

`R=local_user T=maildir_home ST=save_to_db`

I've also added `debug_print = "PG: $sender_address"` to see if something is happening in the logs but the message is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

## Intercept messages and pipe them to an arbitrary command

**exim.conf**:

```
system_filter = /etc/exim/system_filter.conf
```

**system_filter.conf**:

```
if $h_subject contains "PIPETEST"
then
  unseen pipe "/usr/local/bin/pipetest_filter.php $message_size"
endif
```